# JS scrollbar with fluid height

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, css

I'd like to personalize the scrollbar of a div whith a fluid height :

```
section {
max-height:70%;
overflow-y:auto;
}
```

I have found two smart light snippets : a Jquery plugin (http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/) and a pure JS one (http://gondo.webdesigners.sk/javascript-scrollbar/). The problem is that these snippets do not accept % value for the height. For example, with tinyscrollbar, i have to put this :

```
section .viewport {
width: auto;
height:440px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}
```

If I put "height:100%;" or "height:auto;", the content disappears ! Why does it accept px and not % ? I'd like to understand it...

Which part of the JS/JQuery code should I change/add in order to insert the fluid height of the section ?

Comment: In what scenarios would the height of that element change?

Comment: The height would change in accordance with :                   

 - the size of the content (e.g. if I put three lines of text the height would be 60px, but if I put 1000 lines of text the height would not exceed 70% of the screen).                   
- the size of the user window or media (e.g. if it is 600x480, the max-height would be 336px, if it is 1024x768, the max-height would be 538px).

Comment: So, the change occurs (1) when the content is changed, and (2) then the browser window re-sizes. You could just re-initialize the scrolling mechanism on these events.

Comment: I'm sorry but i do not know how to do this (i'm a beginner in JS). Could you paste a snippet so I can understand please ? The snippet for initialization is : <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar();

    });
</script>.

Comment: Tiny-scrollbar provides a `.tinyscrollbar_update()` method. Check out [the documentation on the web-site](http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to follow without more example code (get in the habit of posting more code please), but I think something like this is what you're after.

--- Why don't you track the height of the context (outer div?) and the height of the inner div (section) and calculate them as they change?

```
var context_height = $("#context_div").height();
var section_height = $("section#id").height();

var percentage = section_height / context_height;
var measurement = percentage + "%";

$(section_height).css("height", measurement); // trigger this with a callback if heights need updating - possibly even re-initializing any scroll plugins, if necessary.
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ! The outer div is a #container {position:relative;height:auto!important;min-height:100%;}. So, the {max-height:70%;} of <section> means 70% of the window's height. (I'm not sure about your "section#id" : shouldn't I write "section.viewport" instead ?)

Comment: Sure, you could do that. Section#id was just an example of what you could do if you have an ID set on the section HTML element. For this example they would give you the same result.